# WebView Cuts Off

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I'm using a WebView to display the contents of an IP Camera. I access its browser interface by loading its local ip address into the webview.

When there's only the webview, set to match parent on both width and height (therefore filling the entire screen) it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6Ph2.png). As you can see, the page gets cut off (on the side and on the bottom, and even if I enable scrolling, theres nothing to scroll to, only blank page).
The code I'm using (without scrolling enabled) is this:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {
        handler.proceed("admin","");
    }
});
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.24:81");
```

So I looked for a solution and found some similar questions.
Most of the solutions were a combination of the following lines, right before loadUrl:

```
webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

I've tried all the combinations. With all 4 lines it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1NMC.png). Now it gets cut off at the bottom, but I can still see most of it.

My problem is even worse. Since I want to have the WebView not take the entire screen, but only 50%, I set its height to 0dp, and its weight to half of the weightSum of its Frame parent. Now it looks like this (can't post more than 2 links. Will post in comment). The WebView takes 50% of the screen as intended, but its content gets cut off at the bottom, and as you can see, I can see only about 30% of its top.

This doesnt happen if I loadUrl google for example. I'm sure there's some solution to this problem, however, everything I tried failed, so I turn to you.

Comment: The third image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDX9Z.png